# How to Run Timely Automated Query on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field called `pending` and been declared as Boolean with default value of `0` as:

```
`pending` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

I am running an Update query againt the database to change the state of  q`pending` to `1` like below

```
$sql = "UPDATE  `appointments` SET  `pending` =  '1' WHERE  `appointments`.`id` = 124;
```

now my question is, is there any way to automatically re-state the `pending` to `0` after 30 minutes by taking a conditional clause like

```
// After 30 Minutes of update!
if (!confirmed){
    $sql = "UPDATE  `appointments` SET  `pending` =  '0' WHERE  `appointments`.`id` = 124;
}
```

**Table Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `pending` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Can you include the table schema in your question?

Comment: Have a look at mysql events [ https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/ ]

Comment: do you want to update all pending =1 to pending =0 after 30 minutes? are you using ubuntu?

Comment: so , there can be multiple ids with last updated pending? and are you using ubuntu?

Comment: You normally use whatever scheduled tasks mechanism your operating system provides.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

Make your pending field not a boolean but a datetime, with the value of the due time. Then in your select queries just compare that value with the current time. So instead of

```
SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE pending = 1
```

just make it

```
SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE pending < NOW()
```

this solution is either much simpler and more flexible

Comment: Thanks for the hint but this is not running automatically! I think I still need to manually runt the query, am I right?

Comment: @Behseini you don't have to run any query at all. this is how SQL works.

Comment: I think the addresses the problem in a different way than what OP wanted, but it still addresses the problem.